# SQL-like query in R or creating a loop?

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, aggregate, aggregate-functions

My dataset looks like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNeqi.png)

You can see that the same School-type appears on the same neighborhood.
What I would like to see is if there is a way to end up with a dataset that has the variables :

-School_name

-total_this year = for the same neighborhood sum the no_of_grads_this_year

-total_last_year = for the same neighborhood sum the no_of_grads_last_year

The final goal is to create these two new columns (total_this year, total_last_year) and match them with the school name. So it will look like  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WQBx.png)

What I tried: (Manner of speech, this is not a complete try because it is wrong)

`temp <- data%>%
select(school_name,neighborhood,no_grads_this_year,no_of_grads_last_year)%>%
filter(unique(id))%>%
mutate()` <--- Here I had in mind creating these two new columns and setting them to be the sum of the rows for which the neighborhood indicator is the same. But I don't know how to execute this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you desired output

```
as.data.frame(data %>% group_by (School,Neighbourhood)%>% summarise(sum_this_year= sum(This.Year),sum_last_year = sum(Last.Year)))
```

Comment: uses dplyr and tidyr packages.

Comment: It works! Thanks! Do you recommend a resource to practice on such "queries" in R? I have practiced a bit with dplyr but as I can see now I was way to off from the correct way of putting the requests (grouping by,summarizing) together.

Comment: I would recommend starting with [this](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html), let me know if you find it insufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Base `R` solution:

```
df <- data.frame(school = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
                 neighborhood = c(1,1,2,2,2),
                 no_grads_this_year = c(10,20,40,35,30),
                 no_grads_last_year = c(15,15,80,70,70))

> df
  school neighborhood no_grads_this_year no_grads_last_year
1      A            1                 10                 15
2      A            1                 20                 15
3      B            2                 40                 80
4      B            2                 35                 70
5      B            2                 30                 70

df2 <- aggregate(df[,3:4], list(df$school, df$neighborhood), sum)
names(df2) <- c("School Name", "Neighborhood", "total_this_year", "total_last_year")

> df2
  School Name Neighborhood total_this_year total_last_year
1           A            1              30              30
2           B            2             105             220
```

Comment: It also works, very well put down example, I will try that as well.